# Lunar landing module and orbiting space craft personnel transfer

Tags: the-moon, nasa, apollo-program, jpl

How did the crew of Apollo get from the orbiting capsule into the Lunar lander, as the orbiter rocket engine was between the orbiter and Lunar lander?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How did astronauts traverse from module to module in the Apollo craft?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6245/how-did-astronauts-traverse-from-module-to-module-in-the-apollo-craft)

Comment: Yes excellent, thank you

Comment: I have just seen that there was an engine between Luna lander and Command module. They had to eject from one another turn 180 and them attach for human transfer, ummm got it now,

Answer (score 2):

While the modules were launched with the engine in between, the modules docked nose-to-nose. The crew moved between the modules using hatches in the noses of each module.

[image]

[Image location](https://www.quora.com/How-were-the-Apollo-11s-command-module-Columbia-and-the-lunar-module-eagle-powered-and-steered)

Related questions about the "transposition, docking, and extraction" maneuver:

- [Reasons behind the "Transposition, docking and extraction" maneuver](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/3995/6944)
- [Did the combined Command and Service Module and Lunar Module perform another 180° turn after transposition, docking and extraction?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21994/6944)
- [Docking of Command and Service module with Lunar module](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33313/6944)

Comment: Many thanks for that answer, thousand words in one picture

Comment: You're welcome and welcome to space stack exchange. I added links to some other questions on the site where you can read more about how the docking was actually done.